# How to hard block wifi completely as i want to run internet using ethernet only?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, wireless

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
```

shows `ath9k`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it throught the GUI network settings, but if you want to do it from terminal then use:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

---

A hard lock would be by disabling WI-FI in your BIOS or by blacklisting the module by editing ...

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and adding ...

```
blacklist ath9k
```

Comment: That looks like a a soft block to me :=) Disabling it in BIOS or removing the module would be a hard block. Hope you don't mind the edit ;)

Comment: can you please explain about removing module? @Rinzwind